# Backslash and doublebackslash

Tags: c

I've got a file with paths  . But I can't read them correctly in C . 
an example of a line in the file :

`C:\Trust\The\process.txt`

and I want to have this :

`C:\\Trust\\The\\process.txt`

But how can I replace antislash by double antislash ? 
I've got this function :

```
/*  Replace a string */
char* replace(char* text, char* replace, char* element) {
  int i, j, k;

  int searchSize = strlen(text);
  int replaceSize = strlen(replace);
  int size = strlen(element);

  char* ret;

  if (!searchSize) {
    ret = malloc(size + 1);
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
      ret[i] = element[i];
    }
    return ret;
  }

  int retAllocSize = (strlen(element) + 1) * 2; 
  ret = malloc(retAllocSize);

  int bufferSize = 0; 
  char* foundBuffer = malloc(searchSize); 

  for (i = 0, j = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    if (retAllocSize <= j + replaceSize) {
      retAllocSize *= 2;
      ret = (char*) realloc(ret, retAllocSize);
    }

    else if (element[i] == text[bufferSize]) {
      foundBuffer[bufferSize] = element[i];
      bufferSize++;


      if (bufferSize == searchSize) {
        bufferSize = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < replaceSize; k++) {
          ret[j++] = replace[k];
        }
      }
    }

    else {
      for (k = 0; k < bufferSize; k++) {
        ret[j++] = foundBuffer[k];
      }
      bufferSize = 0;

      ret[j++] = element[i];
    }
  }


  free(foundBuffer);

  return ret;
}
```

I thought I could use like this , but it doesn't work :

```
char *token ;
char s[]="C:\Trust\The\process.txt";
token=replace("\0x5c","\\",s);
```

Comment: 1. There aren't really two backslashes in the string - print it, you'll see. There are tworking backslashes in the *source code* because the first is an escape character. 2. Your string replacement code is very complex. 3. "Doesn't work" is not a problem statement. What *does* it do? Have you stepped through with a debugger? Stack Overflow is not a free debugging service.

Comment: I don't see the difference of what you have (`C:\Trust\The\process.txt`) and what you like to have?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between characters in your program and characters in your source code. When you write "\\" in your source code, you produce a string with a single \ character in your program.

Comment: You don't need to replace "antislash" with "double antislash", except in string literals.   So, if a user enters "c:\a\b" when a string is being read, then that's what will be printed out.     The doubling is only needed in string or character literals in source code  i.e. `char s[]="C:\Trust\The\process.txt"` should be typed in as `char s[]="C:\\Trust\\The\\process.txt"`.   But you don't write code to do that - simply remember to escape backslashes when typing string/character literals in source code.

Comment: @schorsch312 the question was poorly formatted. Look at the edited question

Comment: `int replaceSize = strlen(replace);`. Don't you mean `strlen(rep)`?  How on earth did this compile?

Comment: @andy J  Yes Andy, my bad , I correct it .

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I know, it doesn't show what I want . And it shows nothing .

Comment: @user3121023 I was thinking for that . But it doesn't came from that

Comment: Do you have an accepted answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
char s[]="C:\Trust\The\process.txt";
```

your backslash is gone at compile time. The \T becomes a tab, for example. When you call

```
token=replace("\0x5c","\\",s);
```

the contents of s has already been 'edited' by the compiler and the backslashes are gone.

Your test case needs to be

```
char s[]="C:\\\\Trust\\\\The\\\\process.txt";
```

and when you call the replace function you will have the single backslashes in s.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling comments together, you need to understand that the backslash in a string in C source code is an *escape* charater. It means "the next character has a special meaning".

In order to put a single backslash character in a C string string, you must tell the compiler that "this backslash you must put in the string" and to do that, you put two backslashes in the string *in your source code* so the string in *the compiled code* will have a single backslash. In summary:

```
char s[]= "C:\\my\\dir"";
```

in your source code, will have a string in the compiled code:

```
C:\my\dir
```

Comment: I understand that . But how am I gonna do that automatically ?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. You don't need to do that "automatically". Everything you read in into your running program, from file or user input, is _not_ source code so a backslash read is just a backslash in your string in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading from an input file `input.txt` and each filename ends with a newline, this should work:

```
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 1024
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  /* File read variables */
  FILE *fp;
  char buf[MAX_LINE_LEN];
  char *token;

  /* Open input file */
  fp=fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if(fp == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file.  Exiting...");
    return 1;
  }

  /* Get each line and print result */
  while ((fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) != NULL) {
    token=replace("\\", "\\\\", buf); 
    printf("%s", token);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Input: `input.txt`:

```
C:\Trust\The\process.txt
```

Output:

```
C:\\Trust\\The\\process.txt
```

Comment: Well kinda , except my s will be like this :
  char *s= "C:\\Trust\\The\\process.txt";

Comment: How will you be passing the `s` into your program?  As a cmdline arg? From text file?  Or just within your program?

Comment: From the Text File

Comment: Check my modified answer and see if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion in your problem statement:

The variable definition `char s[]="C:\Trust\The\process.txt";` is incorrect. It should be written:

```
char s[] = "C:\\Trust\\The\\process.txt";
```

The compiler interprets the `\` character in a string literal as an escape character to encode special and non-printing characters. The `\\` represents a single `\` character in the string.

The file contents should not need to have its `\` characters doubled or escaped in any way. Unless you perform some sort of parsing when you read the file, the characters read will be stored untouched in memory and the sequence `C:\Trust\The\process.txt` in the file will be read as a string identical to `s`.